# Transferring Win32 API WndProc Key messages from one window to the other

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, winapi, keyboard, wndproc

I'm developing for Windows Mobile in C++, and I'm running into a problem - I added my window
class, and in it I the keyboard input with my `WndProc` implementation. The problem is
that I'm getting the wrong codes, and identifying keys such as the func key incorrectly, and to make it worse, the values I'm getting (the `wParam` of the `WM_KEYDOWN` message) as different values between the two phones I have here for testing - who knows what will happen on other phones.

After playing around with it for ages, I found out that if I only create a window from the 
predefined "EDIT" class, I actually do get the input correctly (in terms of letters/keys).

So the problem must not be in the phone, but rather the modes of getting messages (a bit of a newbie in win32, excuse me for lack of knowledge). I tried playing around with input modes, but sending a message to my window using EM_NUMBERS and the such, always failed.

So what I would want to do (though I'm open for suggestions), is somehow just get the characters from some hidden EDIT window, and forward them to my window. (Though I still need my window to have the focus so it would react correctly to messages different from `WM_KEYDOWN` and the like)

Is there any way to do this?

This is the 3'rd time I'm asking regarding this issue, i am eternally grateful to everyone who tried to help so far (though would be even more grateful if i had managed to solve my problem)

Here are the relevant code excerpts:

Class registration :

```
WNDCLASS wc; wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;  
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;  
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;  
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;  
wc.hInstance = hInstance;  
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ROADMAP));  
wc.hCursor = 0;  
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);  
wc.lpszMenuName = 0;  
wc.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;  

window creation  
if (width == -1) width = CW_USEDEFAULT;  
if (height == -1) height = CW_USEDEFAULT;  
RoadMapMainWindow = CreateWindow(g_szWindowClass, szTitle, OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,  
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, 
                                 NULL, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);  

MessageLoop  
// Main message loop:  
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))  
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))  
    {  
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg);    
    }  
}
```

WNDPROC excerpt  :

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:  
{  
    WORD Code = (WORD)wParam;  
    int iRepeatTimes = (lParam & 0x0000FFFF);  
    int iScanCode = (lParam & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;  
    BOOL bALT_IsDown = (lParam & 0x20000000)? TRUE: FALSE;  
    BOOL bAlreadyPressed= (lParam & 0x40000000)? TRUE: FALSE;  
    BOOL bNowReleased = (lParam & 0x80000000)? TRUE: FALSE;  
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The wParam of `WM_KEYDOWN` is a virtual key code that is not really constrained to be an ascii (or unicode) character - its simply a code that uniquely identifies the key on the platform.

If you want the 'text' - you want to wait for the `WM_CHAR` message - the wParam of `WM_CHAR` will be the actual character value that the user entered.

---

More Info - in your application loop - where you call `TranslateMessage` - it is actually the job of `TranslateMessage` to spot `WM_KEYDOWN` messages and synthesize and post the corresponding `WM_CHAR` messages.

---

`TranslateAccelerator` seems to be the only thing that can interfere with posted messages.
Of course, sometimes very unusual behaviour can manifest if the windows message proc is (or is not) handing messages to `DefWindowProc` at the wrong time. Why for example do you have an explicit call to `DefWindowProc` in your `WM_KEYDOWN` handler? The easiest way to handle that correctly is to have `DefWindowProc` as the last thing your window proc does so that all messages, handled and unhandled, go there by default. the exceptional case would be messages where you want to prevent `DefWindowProc` getting the message (`WM_PAINT` if you handle it for example).

---

You also keep mentioning trying to use `Edit_SetInputMode` - `Edit_SetInputMode` sends a message to the window: `EM_SETINPUTMODE` - which is a message only understood by EDIT controls. As you have registered your own window class, 'EM_SETINPUTMODE` is going to do nothing.

Comment: i actually have the also a WM_CHAR code, Problem is that 
unfortunately, That's exactly the bug - On some keys i get the KEYDOWN message, but that does not get translated properly to the CHAR messages. ( and sometimes it does get translated, but to a different character  :(    )

Comment: If WM_CHAR isn't what you expect, then you have some bigger problem somewhere and these symtoms are indications of something more fundamental.

Comment: SO what can cause WM_KEYDOWN not to be interpereted to WM_CHAR?
Can you see anything wrong with my class definition?

Comment: So if you make a really, really basic app with just one Window and this handler, do you get the proper messages?

Answer (score 0):

I've not had any problems like you describe, so I'd really like to see a bare-bones set of code that repros this.  It is known that [some phones get spurrious user-range messages](http://www.modaco.com/content/windows-mobile-development-visual-c/242539/windows-mobile-spurious-private-messages-firmware-bug/) but these shouldn't be affecting you at the level you're at.  The fact that you're getting wrong codes for something so basic indicates to me that you must have something wrong in your window creation or message handling code.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing, but maybe your app is an Ansi app? That could maybe explain that different codepages give you different keycodes. So have you tried to make it all Unicode in the project settings, and define the string constants accordingly? And did you try ctacke's suggestion to make a really basic app?